# Understanding the Deduction theorem

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

### Deduction theorem (First order predicate logic)

Suppose there exists a deduction $\Gamma,\phi\vdash\rho$ such that there is not generalized applications in formulas that depends on $\phi$ and also suppose that generalized variable it's a free variable of $\phi$. Then $\Gamma\vdash\phi\to\rho.$

My questions are:

What is the *generalized variable*?

Is the *generalized variable* any generalized variable such that doesn't depend on $\phi$?  But if it doesn't depends on $\phi$ it can't be a free variable of $\phi$.

This is very confusing. Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Is the initial statement a quotation? Where from? It is indeed very unclear!

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes it is. I know, it's very unclear that's why I asked here. My teacher told me it is from Mendelson Logic book, and I searched in the book but I didn't find any similarities.

Comment: @PeterSmith no it's not a quotation, it's a theorem (That's what my teacher said).

Comment: I agree with @PeterSmith that this is very unclear; in fact, I don't think it's a well-formed English sentence. I would suggest, though, that "generalized variable" means a variable $x$ that occurred in a quantifier (probably $\forall x$) that was introduced by a rule of generalization in the deduction of $\rho$ from $\Gamma,\phi$.

Comment: The "generalized variable" is a variable $x$ occurring in some formula in $\Gamma$ or $\phi$ on which the Gen rule is applicated durinf the derivation. See [Deduction Th in predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#The_deduction_theorem_in_predicate_logic).

Comment: For details, see [Mendelson](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA71), page 71.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment*

In a derivation $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, i.e. a sequence $D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_n$ where ... and $D_n= \phi$, we say that $D_i$ *depends upon* $B$ iff:

> 1. $D_i$ is $B$ and the justification for $D_i$ is that it belongs to $\Gamma$, or
> 2. $D_i$ is justified as a direct consequence by **MP** or **Gen** of some preceding formulas of the sequence, where at least one of these preceding formulas depends upon $B$.

With this definition in place, we have:

> *Deduction Theorem*: Assume that, in some deduction showing that $Γ, \phi ⊢ \psi$, no application of **Gen** to a formula that depends upon $\phi$ has as its quantified variable a free variable of $\phi$. Then $Γ ⊢ \phi \to \psi$.

Thus, your "generalized variable" is a variable $x$ having free occurrences in $\phi$ and in the derivation there is some application of **Gen** to a formula that depends upon $\phi$ that quantifies $x$ (that "generalize" on it).

Comment: I thought that the **Gen** rule should not be applied to the formula $\psi$ that depends on $\phi$. I construct an example to try to understand the Deduction Theorem, let me know if I am correct.

Comment: Suppose $\phi\vdash\psi$ and let $\phi=x\to\forall x\phi(x), \rho=x,\psi=\forall x\phi(x)$ (using Modus ponens for $\psi$) .Then $\vdash\phi\to\psi$.

Comment: @Michelle - not clear. Simple example: let $\phi := (x=0)$ Thus: $x=0 \vdash \forall x (x=0)$, by Gen. But now we cannot apply the DT to derive (the invalid): $\vdash (x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$.

Comment: I see, thank you so much:)